# Resize Angular Material Bottom Sheet, when dragged from the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular-material, bottom-sheet

I am using [Angular Material Bottom Sheet](https://material.angular.io/components/bottom-sheet/overview), but I want it in such a way, that it should get adjusted, when the user drags it up and down from the bottom.

I have used one plugin to resize the bottom sheet, but the bottom sheet is getting dragged up and down without resizing, it's bottom is not fixed.

[Here's the working code in plunkar.](http://plnkr.co/edit/MXsh31y4uf6AU8PBgHQ8?p=preview)

**resizer.js:**

```
angular.module('mc.resizer', []).directive('resizer', function($document) {
  return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    $element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
    });

    function mousemove(event) {
      if ($attrs.resizer == 'vertical') {
        // Handle vertical resizer
        var x = event.pageX;

        if ($attrs.resizerMax && x > $attrs.resizerMax) {
          x = parseInt($attrs.resizerMax);
        }

        $element.css({
          left: x + 'px'
        });

        $($attrs.resizerLeft).css({
          width: x + 'px'
        });
        $($attrs.resizerRight).css({
          left: (x + parseInt($attrs.resizerWidth)) + 'px'
        });

      } else {
        // Handle horizontal resizer
        var y = window.innerHeight - event.pageY;
        if((window.innerHeight-100 > y)&&(y>100)){
          $element.css({
            bottom: y + 'px'
          });

          $($attrs.resizerTop).css({
            bottom: (y + parseInt($attrs.resizerHeight)) + 'px'
          });
          $($attrs.resizerBottom).css({
            height: y + 'px'
          });
        }
      }
    }

    function mouseup() {
      $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
      $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this?